# Java Hibernate with Sql Server Express 2008

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I can't configure hiberante with my sql server . I have installed hibernate plugins from eclipse marketplace and at that moment my project icon gets an error but I cant find the file with error sign. I have establish my connection values and ping is successful but when I click finish to get the hibernate config file it wont open and it shows no error it just doesn't finish the request and seems like it can't perform that service . I would very much appreciate your help in advance ! ( There is also another issues I cant access eclipse marketplace anymore since yesterday afternoon it seems it is their problem because I can't  access their website even from another computer or network)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show your hibernate config file, which JAR's you have included into project?

Comment: I have problem with getting that configuration file

Comment: Don't put such information into comments. Please update your question instead!

Comment: The connection is establish and I can send the ping successfully to my server but it seems it is a problem of jbos service it doesn't create the config file in my project at all

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Amogh

Comment: Sorry I am new to SO @GhostCat ,thank your for your advice

Comment: Dont apologize. Simply update your question, and delete the other comments ;-)

Comment: Ok :D thank you @GhostCat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with maven project update ,I hadn't update my project after installing plugins so i couldn't access even eclipse marketplace anymore. After correcting that, I change the version in hibernate configure file wizard  from 5.3 into 4.3 and I was able to get the hibernate.config.xml in my main repository. Hope I can help a beginner like me!